# Tell the source of CursorMoved event in Vim?

Tags: vim

`CursorMoved` event is fired when cursor position changed in Vim, but I don't get the source of this move, like changed by navigation command, or mouse scrolling. Is it possible to detect such difference in Vim script?

Comment: mouse scrolling generates special key presses, like `<ScrollWheelUp/Down...>` I don't know what are you trying to do, if you just want to do something when user scrolled mouse wheel, you can create a mapping, for those keys, and call some function. `:h scroll-mouse-wheel`

Comment: @Kent thanks. I am creating a smooth scroller for Vim navigation commands which utilizes CursorMoved event, but I don't want to do any customized scrolling if it comes from mouse wheel. I will check the help you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

No source is given for the `CursorMoved` event; you just know that the position changed. To get more information, you'd need to extend Vim to provide this information (e.g. via a special `v:keycode` variable). As a (crude) workaround, you could map all movement commands to add that information, but that probably interferes too much, and also doesn't cover any custom motions.